# How to build a query that pulls in a listing of employee ids for employees that have a value that occurred on a range of dates unique to employee?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pull in the distinct employee IDs for any employee who had a corrective action with a list of corrective action type IDs within 180 days of their corrective action date.

so if I have employee John Doe who got a corrective action type id 123 on 07/08/2018 I need to know if he got a corrective action for type IDs 123, 456, or 789 within 180 days before their current corrective action or 60 days after.

[image: Sample Table]

In the above sample table I would want it to bring in Employee ID 1 and 5 as they have had a corrective action within 180 days.

Comment: Sample data and expected output will improve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `join`:

```
select c.*, cnext.*
from corrective c join
     corrective cnext
     on cnext.employee_id = c.employee_id and
        cnext.ca_dt > c.ca_dt - 180 and
        cnext.ca_dt < c.ca_dt + 60 and
        cnext.ca_type in (123, 456, 789)
```

Answer (score 0):

Berto, besides Joakim's request for DDL and sample data you said "current corrective action" which implies last corrective action so how can there be a corrective action 60 days after?  Here is something to look at that might help you phrase your requirements:

```
set echo on
set feedback on

drop table t1;
create table t1 (empid number, corr_action_type number(04), corr_action_date date);
insert into t1 values (7654,123,sysdate - 140);
insert into t1 values (7654,456,sysdate - 092);
insert into t1 values (7654,789,sysdate - 062);
insert into t1 values (7521,123,sysdate - 120);
insert into t1 values (7521,256,sysdate - 120);

select e.*, c.*
from   emp e
join (select empid,
             min(corr_action_date) oldest,
             max(corr_action_date) mostrecent
      from   t1 where corr_action_type in (123,456,789)
             group by empid
      ) c
on c.empid = e.empno
where
  ( c.oldest <>  c.mostrecent and
    c.oldest >   c.mostrecent - 180
 )
/
```

Comment: thank you! I am trying to figure out how to verbalize the request as best as possible without using real data because of confidentiality. I am looking at a table that has millions of rows and I need to pull in those employees that have had a corrective action within 180 days previous a given corrective action and 61 days after a given corrective action. thank you for this query! A variation of this may work. I will try it out now.

Comment: this gets me close, but in my case I have employees that have more than just three corrective actions in a year and while the oldest one is older than 180 days and the most recent one is more 61 days from a given date there may be a 4th one that does fall into that pre 180 or post 61.